# Oneclick JS button on Quote: not able to get the opportunity field info

Tags: javascript

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")} 
    var Quote = new sforce.SObject("Quote");
    Quote.Id = '{!Quote.Id}';
    var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT opportunity.License__c from quote WHERE id ='{!Quote.Id}' LIMIT 1");
    var records = result.getArray("records");
    alert(records[0]);    
    var sl = '{!JSENCODE(TEXT(records[0].opportunity.License__c))}' ;
```

> Alert output: {type:'Quote', Id:null, Opportunity:{type:'Opportunity', Id:null,
>   License__c:'Y', }, }
>
> Error message: A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button
>   or link was encountered: Cannot read property 'License__c' of
>   undefined

Comment: you should check `records[0].opportunity.License__c` in alert/ console?

Comment: still no luck here is there JS error that im getting: A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

Cannot read property 'License__c' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JavaScript` is case sensitive, and you are trying to access a lower case `Opportunity` field. Try with code below:

```
var sl = '{!JSENCODE(TEXT(records[0].Opportunity.License__c))}'
```